# Error launching PyCharm: Failed to load JVM DLL

Tags: jvm, pycharm

I installed PyCharm before to learn Python, after that I installed Eclipse to learn JAVA too.  By the way, now I have no problem lauching Eclipse, but when I launch PyCharm, I see the error message as below:

> Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll
>
> If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

[image]

How can I launch PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Found solution. just execute Pycharm 64bit..

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10, try running as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by deleting the jvm.dll file in C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\jbr\bin\server.
Then it started actually looking up the JAVA_HOME variable and the programme launched.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the following file:
`C:\Users\'your user'\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\`

and then you can launch PyCharm as the first time you start.